# Can I please have a list of all my deleted questions and answers, score < 0?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

A moderator commented on a question of mine showing 8 deleted questions with score below 0. I looked through them, salvaged 2 of the questions, but perhaps there are others I can savage? And what about the same for answers? Please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The list of 8 questions that the moderator provided to you was complete. You only had 8 deleted questions. Since you apparently undeleted the 2 you salvaged, you now have only 6 deleted questions. They are, in reverse chronological order:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59252896/why-isnt-applicationwillterminate-not-getting-called-when-the-application-clo
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55892756/how-can-i-translate-pixels-fraction-of-screen
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55192791/how-to-make-an-empty-space-between-gtk-widgets
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55090546/how-come-i-am-getting-weird-outcomes-when-calling-functions-from-an-array
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53679031/how-can-i-open-a-file-without-requiring-a-full-path
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53655193/converting-a-hexadecimal-character-array-to-hexadecimal-number

You have 13 deleted answers. They are, in reverse chronological order:

- [How can I concatenate 4 bytes to 8 in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60694929/how-can-i-concatenate-4-bytes-to-8-in-c/60696631#60696631)
- [How to iterate through a struct array in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60688172/how-to-iterate-through-a-struct-array-in-c/60688221#60688221)
- [What determines whether segmentation fault occurs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60644429/what-determines-whether-segmentation-fault-occurs/60644457#60644457)
- [Keyword between a datatype and a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60638456/keyword-between-a-datatype-and-a-variable/60638693#60638693)
- [c++ rounding of numbers away from zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326510/c-rounding-of-numbers-away-from-zero/59899777#59899777)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59888349/segmentation-fault-when-modifying-2d-arrays-in-void-function/59888550#59888550
- [Why char * c = NULL; causes an error in the following code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59870656/why-char-c-null-causes-an-error-in-the-following-code/59870945#59870945)
- [How can I add together the numbers in a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59867742/how-can-i-add-together-the-numbers-in-a-file/59869344#59869344)
- [Why use binary files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438415/why-use-binary-files/59775059#59775059)
- [Is NULL always false?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459743/is-null-always-false/59022653#59022653)
- [Is there way to hard code a two dimensional integer array without having to mention any dimension in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58349966/is-there-way-to-hard-code-a-two-dimensional-integer-array-without-having-to-ment/58349993#58349993)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57892555/assembly-vs-c-efficiency-for-generating-hex-file/57892601#57892601
- [Did I correctly translate this pseudocode into Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53963744/did-i-correctly-translate-this-pseudocode-into-java/53963849#53963849)

Note that you are *not* currently banned from answering (although you were back in February). Thus, I'd recommend not trying to dredge up and improve old answers. Just focus on posting high-quality answers from now forward.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55892756/how-can-i-translate-pixels-fraction-of-screen seems like a goodish quesiton, but it got downvoted and closed because I phrased it really wierd.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55892756/how-can-i-translate-pixels-fraction-of-screen no longer deleted